# How to Check Whether mysqli connection is open before closing it

Tags: php, mysqli

I am going to use `mysqli_close($connection)` to close the `$connection`. But Before Closing I need to ensure that the concerned connection is open.

I tried

```
if($connection)
{
  mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

But it is not working. Any Solution?

Comment: `$connection` returns true or `close()` returns true?

Comment: @Baez `if($connection)` returns true

Comment: That's because the object still exists. The close method within mysqli sets its parametres to NULL.

Comment: See the edits in my answer. You can use the `$connected` boolean to determine whether you've closed that connection.

Answer (score 47):

This is from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php).

> Object oriented style
>
> ---
>
> ```
> <?php
> $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
>
> /* check connection */
> if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
>     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
>     exit();
> }
>
> /* check if server is alive */
> if ($mysqli->ping()) {
>     printf ("Our connection is ok!\n");
> } else {
>     printf ("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
> }
>
> /* close connection */
> $mysqli->close();
> ?>
> ```
>
> Procedural style
>
> ---
>
> ```
> <?php
> $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
>
> /* check connection */
> if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
>     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
>     exit();
> }
>
> /* check if server is alive */
> if (mysqli_ping($link)) {
>     printf ("Our connection is ok!\n");
> } else {
>     printf ("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
> }
>
> /* close connection */
> mysqli_close($link);
> ?>
> ```

Comment: If the connection was closed before, it throws: `mysqli::ping(): Couldn't fetch mysqli`.

Comment: Continuing on Leopoldo's comment, what about if we try-catch a ping, e.g. `try { return $db->ping(); } catch (Throwable) { return false; }`? I suppose `ping()` could theoretically return errors even if the connection is technically up and working? But I'm not sure..

Answer (score 14):

While some suggest to check for `$connection->ping()`,`$connection->stat()` or `mysqli_thread_id($connection)`, the three will throw: '`Couldn't fetch mysqli`' if the connection was closed before.

The solution that worked for me was:

```
if(is_resource($connection) && get_resource_type($connection)==='mysql link'){
    $connection->close(); //Object oriented style
    //mysqli_close($connection); //Procedural style 
}
```

PS: Checking only if it's a [resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) could be enough in a controlled context.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (anymore) in PHP 8.1.12 at least :(

Answer (score 8):

you can check if mysqli server info is set.

```
$connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if(!isset($connection->server_info)){
    echo 'sql connection is closed';
}else{
    $connection -> close();
}
```

Comment: This won't tell you if the connection has been dropped by MySQL server. It will only inform you about the state of mysqli object.

Comment: I am also checking if $connection is set and that $connection->connect_error is not present

Answer (score 6):

Just don't close it. That would be the best solution ever.

99.9% of time it's perfectly ok to leave the connection alone, PHP will close it for you.

Only if your script has to perform some heavy time consuming task that doesn't involve a database interaction, you may want to close the connection before starting this operation. But in this case you will have the connection deliberately open as there will be no random closures scattered around the code and therefore will be no need to check whether it is closed already. Hence, just close it, in this particular but extremely rare case.

All other time just leave it alone.

Comment: But that Will Cause too Many Connections opened.

Comment: No it won't.... What causes too many connections errors is you not having enough connections for the amount of load being put onto the db. Not not closing them.

Comment: Is it a Professional Approach to Leave the Connections Opened?

Comment: Its fine/perfectly acceptible and actually puts less load on the server as you're not having to constantly open and reclose connections instead they're just sat there in the pool until they're needed.

Comment: Ok, that's good for me. But I have a confusion. If a Connection is opened and I request one more connection, will this opened connection be used or the new one be opened?

Comment: It doesn't magically stay open. You need to set persistent connections to be on. Otherwise the script will kill the connection at it's end.

Comment: Just prepend p: before  the server hostname on mysqli to set them to persistant connections.  But no it will only open a new connection if a new connection is required otherwise it'll always reuse an existing connection if there's one sat there doing nothing.

Comment: @Munib are you asking for the same running script instance or different one? Frankly - is it for the same script you need second connection or another script?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not on the same script but on some other script

Comment: @Munib new connection will be opened. that's how all PHP scripts works.

Comment: This is what I've put together for personal use. Well, a very watered down version at least. http://pastebin.com/8kcs7qbw

Comment: What causes too many connections is exactly do not close them, this is basic but fatal error that bring a mysql server down

Comment: @FedericoSchiocchet your ideas are completely wrong. PHP closes all connections automatically when the script execution is ended.

Answer (score 4):

If you open a connection, it will stay open until it's explicitly closed or the script ends (unless persistent connections is on). Using the code you have should work.

One option is to extend the `mysqli` class and have a status property called `$connected`:

```
class CustomMysqli extends mysqli
{
    protected bool $connected;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        parent::__construct($host, $username, $password, $database);
        $this->connected = ($this->connect_errno === 0);
    }

    public function close(): void
    {
        if ($this->connected) {
            parent::close();
            $this->connected = false;
        }
    }

    public function isConnected(): bool
    {
        return $this->connected;
    }
}
```

Checking for the `$connected` property is a bit overkill, but will ensure the connection is still open.

Comment: why the connection is returned in class constructor ?

Comment: @AndreiTodorut So that when you connect to a database, you're now able to connect using `$conn = new CustomMysqli(...);` instead

Comment: Is this tested code? [rhetorical question, the answer is clearly "no"]  I don't see any link between the `CustomMysqli` object, and `$conn` - the `mysqli` object. As written, `close` will never get called. (And if it did get called, $conn might not be from the same CustomMysqli - this is a mess. )This code is *not* an example of *extending* class `mysqli` - that would look like `CustomMysqli extends mysqli` and `parent::construct($host, $username, $password, $dbname);`  Also, AFAIK, returning a value from a constructor is meaningless - that isn't how constructors work.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve This answer is more than 7 years old. From what I remember back then, there was an issue with _truly_ extending the `mysqli` class, but I could be mistaken. I've updated the answer to a modern approach, though I recommend using `PDO` instead.

Comment: Thanks - looks good now - the original problem does not exist in this updated code - now you have access to the mysqli `close` via parent inheritance. (Though I haven't tested.) [I'm maintaining legacy code that uses mysqli.]

Comment: FWIW (not that it matters now): If you weren't able to extend mysqli class, a working version of the original broken approach would have been to make a "proxy class": to *wrap* the created `mysli` object - you would have stored it in a field e.g. `private $mysqli;` and `$this->mysqli = new mysqli ...;` then you would have called `$this->mysqli->close();`. [Sorry, being pedantic now.]

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because calling functions on the connection would throw a `couldn't fetch mysqli` error if it was already closed. I ended up inspecting the `mysqli` object before and after closing the connection:

```
// Before calling $connection->close()

object(mysqli)#92 (18) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(14) "mysqlnd 7.4.23"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(11111)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(73) "host.rds.com via TCP/IP"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["server_info"]=>
  string(10) "1.1.1-log"
  ["server_version"]=>
  int(11111)
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  int(10)
  ["thread_id"]=>
  int(1234567)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
}

// After calling $connection->close()

object(mysqli)#92 (3) {
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(11111)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Based on that info, I just wrote the following simple function:

```
private function isClosed() : bool
{
    return !is_int($this->connection->thread_id);
}
```

Comment: I get "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: mysqli object is already closed"

Comment: @Dharman Interesting, that looks like new behavior with PHP 8, so I guess you're on that? Can you not access any properties of the object then?

Comment: I can only access the three that are available after it is closed.

Answer (score -2):

Check connection errors. mysqli_connect() always returns a MySQLi object.

use this:

```
$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
   echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
}
else
{
   echo "Connected.";
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
function close_connection(){
    $thread = $mysqli->thread_id;
    $mysqli->close();
    $mysqli->kill($thread);

}
```

That will close the connection you opened using object oriented style like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_server, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
```

That's the basic idea, but if you're using the procedural style, I'm sure you'll be able to custom the code as you need.

Comment: The mysqli_thread_id() or $mysqli->thread_id function returns the thread ID for the current connection, so you'll be able to kill this very connection.

Comment: Have you tried this code? It appears to throw an exception. `mysqli::kill(): Couldn't fetch mysqli` after closing the connection.